# Assistance on recognizing user input

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Type start to start");
string abc = Console.ReadLine();
if (abc = "start");
```

So, I wanted to make a quiz with the few knowledge I got from watching 3 tutorials on c#, but I cant seem to find a way to make it recognize if the user wrote start or not. Help?

Comment: FYI: `=` is an assignment, `==` is a comparison.

Comment: And why `;` at the end of the `if` statement...

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job

```
Console.WriteLine("Type start to start");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "start"){
    //DoSomething
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks :D, didn't expect to get an answer so soon

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator, `==`. Making that single change will allow your code to run as you expect.

However, unless there is other input you want to allow the user to enter, it may be better to just let them press any key in order to start (if they don't want to start, why would they type anything at all?). If this is an option, you can use the `Console.ReadKey` method, which reads (and returns) the next keypress from the console window.

For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you really do want to examine what they enter (like in a menu system, for example), then you may want to do a case-insensitive comparison instead of using `==` with a hard-coded string. In this case, the `Equals` method of the `string` class has an override that allows you to specify a case-insensitive comparison:

```
// An endless loop, until the user enters a valid command, when we break or exit.
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Type 'start' to begin, or 'quit' to exit: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input.Equals("start", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // They entered 'start', so we can exit the loop and start our code
        Console.WriteLine("Program starting!");
        break; // This exits the 'while' loop, and the program continues
    }

    if (input.Equals("quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Exit the program (the whole program quits so we don't need a break
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // Let them know the input was invalid, and the loop will continue
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a recognized command, please try again");
    }
}

// Code execution will continue here if they type "start"
Console.Write("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you :D, I knew about this but forgot. thanks anyways